# Better results in Document similarity using Word2Vec

Tags: machine-learning, word-embeddings, word2vec, text-classification, similarity

I try to cluster similar support-tickets in a technical domain. The support tickets are very domain-specific and are written in various styles, lengths, using abbreviation, etc.

I made a training-corpus of over 700.000 lines of text. (A total of over 2 milion sentences) The korpus was thoroughly cleaned. Stopwords were removed and tokens lemmatised.

I trained gensim Word2Vec on this korpus and validated the model aginst a test dataset. The dataset consists of about 500 tickets that are in maybe 40 different clusters. Now after many tries the best my model can achieve is about 20% hits and 65% false positivs. (The word similarities however, are very acurate. Using those wordvectors in document-classification is when things get inacurate)

I tried the model on live data and again, it finds similar tickets and clusters them, but it mixes in a lot of noise and probably misses a lot of tickets.

For the document vektor i use the following code:

```
for row in data.index:
        doc = nlp(data.at[row, 'Text'])
        tokens = ' '.join(token.lemma_.lower() for token in doc if token.pos_ in (
            'NOUN',
            'PROPN',
            'VERB',
            'ADV',
            'ADJ'
        )and not token.is_stop and token.lower_ not in wordlist)
        data.at[row, 'Tokens'] = tokens
data = data[data.Tokens != '']
data.loc[:, ('Vektoren')] = data['Tokens'].map(lambda s: nlp(s).vector)
```

One idea i have is to train a NER Model first, filter out all Entitys and build a second vector from those. And then combine the NER-Vector and Text-Vector with different weights.

I would be very thankfull for some advice on how to achieve better accuracy

Oh and theese are the final training parameters:

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(token_lists,
                               min_count=5,
                               sg=0,
                               cbow_mean=0,
                               vector_size=300,
                               sample=0.00001,
                               negative=5,
                               ns_exponent=0.75,
                               window=20,
                               alpha=0.025,
                               min_alpha=0.0001,
                               workers=cores - 1,
                               callbacks=[loss_logger],
                               compute_loss=True,
                               epochs=10)
return model
```

Comment: Please explain a bit better how you get the document vector. Unfortunately, your code is not self-explanatory: you are using some attributes and functions (e.g. ``nlp``) that are not documented, here.

Comment: Sorry! I use spacy for tokenisation. The nlp object creates the pipeline to access tokens, pos-tags and vectors. So i use nlp to extract relevant tokens first and add them to a list. In the final line i access the list of tokens and use spacy on them again to generate a vector-representation of the text. Sapcy does this be generating a mean vector of all wordvectors from the token list